# Issue in sorting QTableView item in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have created a QTable view and connected it to a QSqlTableModel and i am displaying the resulted Query retrived from the database.In QTable view i have enabled sortEnabled option. All the expected results are printing but if i click the sort indicator
the whole data in the table is getting emptyed. Can any one suggest me how to overcome this issue

This is the snap shot of the results table.

[image: snap shot of the results]

This is the snap shot of the results table after pressing sort indicator.

[image: results after pressing sort indicator]

Can any one suggest me how to overcome this issue

Comment: Please post you code, it's quite difficult to say what's going on by just the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out why QTableView's setSortingEnabled method wasn't working is, It turns out the sort method in QAbstractItemModel is not implemented. So you have to implement it yourself.

One solution would be creating a QAbstract view. below is a [code snippet](http://pastebin.com/eFCN7Zzr).

I'm not sure if this is the best way to implement the sort method, but I couldn't find anything else out there, and this seems to work for me.

Comment: I think what you are suggesting is to create a custom model subclass, not a view, right? The view stays the same according to your snippet. Just the model gets a custom `sort` method. Also... `QSqlTableModel` sort is implemented. The `QAbstractItemModel` is not. So I am not sure this is exactly the reason.

Comment: @jdi You are right, View has no change but the QAbstractItemModel will implement its sort which will sort